# Olives in olive oil

Tags: storage, olive

I have a jar of commercially-produced stuffed olives in garlicky olive oil.  They're rather nice considering they were only cheap.  On the jar it says once opened they should be kept in the fridge, which seems fair enough.  However this makes the oil solid and opaque. It's not easy to get the olives out and they're not pleasant to eat with a thick layer of grease on the surface.

Assuming I want to get out a portion of a few olives (rather than the remaining 3/4 of the jar) what's the best way to deal with them? I'd quite like to use up the oil when I've eaten the olives too -- having fried some onions in a sample of it, it has a good flavour.

Comment: plan ahead...scoop out a few...let them come to room temp...enjoy?

Comment: @moscafj Sounds like an answer to me. :)

Comment: @moscafj if that really is the only/best way  then I'll have to accept it (in two senses)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plan ahead...scoop out a few...let them come to room temperature.  You could also experiment with the microwave...10 seconds or so.  Finally, there are multiple recipes for roasted olives that would also solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you dislike the extra cold grainy oil clinging  to the olives (see moscafj’s answer), you can also let the whole jar come to room temperature, scoop out some of the olives and refrigerate the rest again. This should not be a problem, safety-wise, as you are not dealing with spoil-prone food here. And it means that the excess oil stays in the jar and can be used otherwise.
You still need to plan ahead though.

Comment: You could also take the jar out and bring it up to room temperature.  Once they warm up, you could transfer the olives to a clean empty jar and fill with water and a bit of vinegar to cover the olives.  You still have your other bottle  of the oil to use separately from the olives.